Finding the taylor expansion of $f(z) = \frac{1} {1-z-z^2}$ at $z=0$

Consider the function $f(z) = \dfrac{1}
{1-z-z^2}$. Defined over the complex numbers. Find the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $z=0$.

Finding each order derivative at $0$ is a lengthy and time-consuming method. Is there any simple method? I know the expansion of $\dfrac{1}{1-z}$. Is there any way to connect this to $f(z)$? I have no idea how to start this.

First of all notice that $z^2+z-1 = 0$ has two real roots that is $\alpha$ and $\beta$, where $\alpha = \frac{\sqrt{5} -1}{2}$and $\beta = \frac{-\sqrt{5} -1}{2}$.
Now $$f(z) = \frac{1}
{1-z-z^2} 
\\ = -\frac{1}
{z^2 + z - 1}
\\= -\frac{1}
{(z-\alpha)(z-\beta)}
\\= \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{1}
{z-\beta} - \frac{1}
{z-\alpha})
\\ = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}}(\frac{(1-z/\alpha)^{-1}}
{\alpha} - \frac{(1-z/\beta)^{-1}}
{\beta})$$
Now you can break as Taylor series when $|z| < \min\{|\alpha|,|\beta|\}$.
